# Looking for detailed Social Security calculators or formulas for Excel or PowerShell

Tags: finance

I know that calculating the optimal age at which to begin withdrawing from Social Security depends on a number of factors. I haven't seen a SS calculator that is sophisticated enough to include all of them: Current age, spouse's age, expected life expectancy for each.
Simply put, I'm trying to maximize the NPV of our SS income. I know it's not as simple as "Take the benefits at 67, your Full Retirement Age" since the benefit amount increases every month between age 62 and 70. So I'm looking for a calculator (failing that, the already-worked-out formulas) that will result in, say, "Given you and your spouse's ages and contributions, your optimal NPV will occur when you are 66 and 7 months, and she is 67 and 10 months".

Thanks for any help.

I have looked at simple online calculators like those at SSA.gov and https://excelbuddy.com/create-a-social-security-calculator-in-excel/. They will project the outcome, given a specific set of circumstances, but they often don't take into account my wife's taking the spousal benefit and the difference in our ages and life expectancies.